# Aura component is not visible in Salesforce Mobile app

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have written a Aura component. I also need to make is visible on Salesforce Mobile App. But except Comapct Layout, I am not seeing the Aura Component in Mobile app. Please help.

```
    <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable" access="global" 
                controller="SurveyDetailsController">
    
    <aura:attribute name="SurveyResponse" type="Survey_Response2__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="upperFields" type="String[]" default="['AccountId','ContactId','Contact_Role__c','ContactEmail','ContactMobile',
                                                                'ContactEmail','Contact_Role__c','Priority','Origin',
                                                                'Subject','Description','SuppliedEmail',]" />
    <aura:attribute name="bottomFields" type="String[]" default="['Meeting_Call_Outcome__c','Status','Call_Highlights_Visit_Summary__c',
                                                                 'Thematic__c','RecordType','CreatedDate','LastModifiedDate','OwnerId','RecordTypeId']" />
    <!-- event handlers -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    
    <lightning:recordForm aura:id="upperFields"
                          recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                          objectApiName="Case"
                          fields="{!v.upperFields}"
                          columns="2"
                          mode="readonly"/>
    
    <br></br>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered" role="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="slds-text-title--caps" scope="col" rowspan="2" style="width: 15%;">Survey Response</th>
                <th class="slds-text-title--caps" scope="col" style="width: 15%;">Score</th>
                <td>{!v.SurveyResponse.Score__c} / 10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="slds-text-title--caps" scope="col" style="width: 15%;">Verbatim</th>
                <td><lightning:formattedRichText value="{!v.SurveyResponse.Verbatim__c}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <br></br>
    
    <lightning:recordForm aura:id="bottomFields"
                          recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                          objectApiName="Case"
                          fields="{!v.bottomFields}"
                          columns="2"
                          mode="readonly" />
</aura:component>
```

[image]